# Is there any way to avoid an object.prototype.constructor when creating a tic tac toe game with javascript?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I created a tic tac toe game with JavaScript and took a purely functional approach. However, now I am stuck because I can't seem to be able to make the player be able to choose between x and o. The player is automatically assigned x, but never o.  I'm using bootstrap, and I have a modal that appears when the user lands on the page. I have to fulfill a user story in which the user can choose between x and o via the modal buttons. Then the opposite symbol, ie o, would be on the tic tac toe board when the modal is dismissed. That part works fine right now. HOWEVER, if the user is to choose o, and x appears on the board, when the user clicks on a square, another x appears. I don't want an x to appear. An o should appear instead. So basically the user is playing against the board (or you could call it computer if you like), but is able to choose whether he/she wants to play as x or o by pressing on either the x or o button in the modal. Is there any way of making this possible without having to create an object.prototype.constructor? The link to my github repo: https://interglobalmedia.github.io/xoApp/ - sorry for the initial dead link- now it works!

```
function fetchBoard() {
   var board = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''];
   $(".game-field").each(function (index) {
       board[index] = $(this).html();
   });
   return board;
}

/* return 1 if all params 'x', -1 if o, and otherwise 0 */
function checkRow(a, b, c) {
    if (a === 'x' && b === 'x' && c === 'x') {
        return 1;
    } else if (a === 'o' && b === 'o' && c === 'o') {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
function checkWin(board) {
    return checkRow(board[0], board[1], board[2]) // rows
    + checkRow(board[3], board[4], board[5])
    + checkRow(board[6], board[7], board[8])
    + checkRow(board[0], board[3], board[6]) // columns
    + checkRow(board[1], board[4], board[7])
    + checkRow(board[2], board[5], board[8])
    + checkRow(board[0], board[4], board[8]) // main diagonal rows
    + checkRow(board[2], board[4], board[6]) // reverse diagonal row
}

function selectMove(board) {
    var i, options;
    options = [];
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i += 1) {
        if (board[i] === '') {
            options.push(i);
        }
    }
    if (options.length === 0) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)];
    }
}

function showGameOver(result) {
    var target = $("#result");
    if (result > 0) {
        target.css('color', '#db0000');
        target.html("you win!");
    } else if (result < 0) {
        target.css('color', "#db0000");
        target.html("i win!");
    } else {
        target.css('color', '#db0000');
        target.html("tie game.");
    }
}

function resetGame() {
    var target;
    $(".game-field").html('');
    target = $("#result");
    target.css('color', '#db0000');
    target.html('click a square');
}

function moveAt() {
    var xCell, board, result, oLocation, oCell;
    xCell = $(this);

    if (xCell.html() !== '' || checkWin(fetchBoard()) !== 0) {
        return;
    }
    xCell.css('color', '#db0000');
    xCell.html('x');
    board = fetchBoard();
    result = checkWin(board);
    if (result !== 0) {
        showGameOver(result);
        return;
    }
    oLocation = selectMove(board);
    if (oLocation < 0) {
        showGameOver();
        return;
    }
    board[oLocation] = 'o';
    oCell = $('#cell' + oLocation);
    oCell.css('color', '#fff');
    oCell.html('o');

    result = checkWin(board);
    if (result !== 0) {
        showGameOver(result);
        return;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#iconModal').modal('show');
    $('.game-field').click(moveAt);
    $('#tictacreset').click(resetGame);
    resetGame();
});

[1]: https://github.com/interglobalmedia/xoApp/tree/master/src/html
```

Comment: What do you mean "create an object.prototype.constructor?" If you're talking about creating a class, that can be optional, but I'm not sure what end result you're going for.

Comment: Well where do you let the user choose between x and o? Looks like you just have it hardcoded to x.

Comment: I want to keep my code here consistent and be able to just create the ability for a user to choose between x and o with named functions, not function expressions ie `var o = {};
o.constructor === Object; // true

var a = [];
a.constructor === Array; // true

var n = new Number(3);
n.constructor === Number; // true` or `function Tree(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

var theTree = new Tree('Redwood');
console.log('theTree.constructor is ' + theTree.constructor);`

Comment: Yes. Currently it is "hardcoded" to x. I'm trying to figure out a way of undoing that.

Answer (score 0):

> now I am stuck because I can't seem to be able to make the player be able to choose between x and o. The player is automatically assigned x, but never o.

How are the players assigned? Is this just meant to be played locally on the same browser? When the mouse is clicked, a player's turn is over, and then it is the next player's turn?

> Is there any way of making this possible without having to create an object.prototype.constructor?

I might recommend you look at the Kestrel ('constant') combinator

```js
const K = x => y => x

const p1 = K('x')
const p2 = K('o')

console.log(p1(), p2(), p1(), p2())
// x o x o
```

with `K`, you can pass any value in and all subsequent calls to the resulting function will result in the initial value. If you wanted to associate any other data with a player, you could use `K(['x', otherData])` and continue building selectors as needed.

---

Or you could define the player using a lambda, I've chosen two fields here, but there's practically no limit on how many you could implement in this way. Add as many as you'd like ^_^

```js
const player = (name,marker) => p => p(name,marker)
const playerName = p => p((name,marker) => name)
const playerMarker = p => p((name,marker) => marker)

const p1 = player('Bob', 'x')
const p2 = player('Alice', 'o')

console.log(playerName(p1), playerMarker(p1))
// Bob x

console.log(playerName(p2), playerMarker(p2))
// Alice o
```

I hope I understood the intent of your question and that the information provided here is helpful in some way. If not, please let me know. I'm happy to helper further.

Comment: Not exactly. I wasn't able to put all my code here, but have provided the link to the github repo with the initial question. I'm using bootstrap, and I have a modal that appears when the user lands on the page.

Comment: Right now it is set to x. However, I have to fulfill a user story in which the user can choose between x and o via the modal buttons. Then the opposite symbol, ie o, would be on the tic tac toe board when the modal is dismissed. That part works fine right now. HOWEVER, if the user is to choose o, and x appears on the board, when the user clicks on a square, another x appears. I don't want an x to appear. An o should appear instead.

Comment: So basically the user is playing against the board (or you could call it computer if you like), but is able to choose whether he/she wants to play as x or o by pressing on either the x or o button in the modal. Perhaps I didn't explain it clearly enough in the question. I'm trying to do something a bit different here (at least I think it is), and any help would be very much appreciated!